# Square root of Lebesgue integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

Is the square root of a Lebesgue integrable function always integrable?

Thanks!

Comment: Ouch, silly question :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, with the usual definition that "Lebesgue integrable" means $\int |f|<\infty$. Just take 
$$
f(x)=\frac1{x^2}\,1_{[1,\infty)}.
$$
Then 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f=\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}=1,
$$
but $\sqrt{f}=\frac1x\,1_{[1,\infty)}$, and so
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sqrt{f}=\infty
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ on $[1,\infty)$.